# Why is accuracy 0 when training with CNN, where is my error?

Tags: python, machine-learning, testing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

My dataset consists of images and has 3 classes. My classes are While labeling these classes and my images, I made and saved my class labels in the .npy file. I converted the images I resized to the .npy file and saved it as a numpy array. My total tagged data count was. I want to divide this data set into train and test and insert it into the model with CNN and accuracy: 0.0000e+00. What could be the reason?

```
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #plotting
import numpy as np
import os #to access directory
from tqdm import tqdm #counting files
#Data Genaration
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator #for generate transformation of images

import seaborn as sns #visual beautification
import cv2
import io #input/ouput from local
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils import shuffle #shuffles matrics randomly with continuation of same pattern
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator  #augmentation, annotation
from tensorflow.keras.applications import EfficientNetB7 #B0-B7

#EarlyStopping: to avoid overfitting
#ReduceLROnplateau: Reduce Learning Rate based on weight
#TensorBoard: Visualization toolkit of tensorflow
#ModelCheckpoint: save the model or weight at every epoch for improve performance and avoid repeat

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical #encoding

#result checking
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay

from warnings import filterwarnings #ignore deprecation
from PIL import Image #pillow for image open, rotate and display

import ipywidgets as widgets  #for button
from IPython.display import display, clear_output 
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm
import io
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.utils import shuffle # Shuffle arrays or sparse matrices in a consistent way
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

from tensorflow.keras.applications import EfficientNetB7
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, TensorBoard,ModelCheckpoint

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model

import ipywidgets as widgets
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

trainX=np.load(r'resized_images.npy')
trainY=np.load(r'data_label.npy')
#trainX = np.expand_dims(trainX, axis=3)
print(trainX.shape, trainY.shape)


trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(trainX, trainY,test_size=0.30, stratify=trainY, random_state=42)

efficient = EfficientNetB7(weights =None, include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 1))

import tensorflow as tf
#pooling can be avg or max
#dropout range 0.3 -0.5 which means 30-50% neurons will be dropped to avoid overfitting
model=efficient.output
model=tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(model)
model=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(model)
model=tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="softmax")(model)
model=tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=efficient.input, outputs=model)

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", 
              optimizer="adam", 
              metrics =["accuracy"])
#.h5 = Hierarchical Data Format Ver. 5 file, verbose =1, to see execution
tensorboard= TensorBoard(log_dir="logs")
checkpoint= ModelCheckpoint("efficient.h5",
                           monitor="val_accuracy", verbose=1,
                           mode="auto", save_best_only=True)
#monitor: quantity to be monitored.     
#factor: factor by which the learning rate will be reduced. 
#patience: number of epochs with no improvement after which learning rate will be reduced.     
#verbose: int. 0: quiet, 1: update messages.
#min_delta: early stopping of epochs
reduce_lr=ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="val_accuracy",
                           factor=0.5,
                           patience=3,verbose=1,
                           mode="auto", min_delta=0.001)

history = model.fit(trainX, trainY,
                   validation_split=0.30,
                   epochs=20, verbose=1,
                   batch_size=16,
                   callbacks =[tensorboard, checkpoint, reduce_lr])
```

Why is accuracy 0 when training with CNN, where is my error?

Comment: You should print the output of a forward pass. Very likely the way your intended labels and output labels of the network don't match, because your network should be correct by chance at least sometimes. I cannot see you transforming the labels to one hot encoding in the code, which would be necessary for multi-class classification, have you done that already before saving to file?

Comment: I didn't do one hot encoding, in which section should I do this? Is it not enough for me to save the strings by labeling 1, 2, 3 while tagging? (.npy file)

Comment: Between loading the data from file and splitting into training and testing data would be good in your case. You are using [`tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy) which requires your labels to be one hot encoded.

Comment: Softmax with one neuron makes no sense, think about it.

Answer (score 1):

According our discussion, I modified your code:

1. I used transfer learning based on imagenet.
2. I changed your loss function to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` related to your trainY
3. I added a `Lambda` layer to convert your grayscale image (1 channel) to RGB image (3 channels) to be compatible with EfficientNetB7 (with imagenet weights)

For demonstration purpose, I keep only the core code. Feel free to move it to your own code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import EfficientNetB7

trainX = np.load('resized_images.npy')
trainY = np.load('data_label.npy')

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((trainX, trainY))

# EfficientNetB7: trained on 3 channel images
efficient = EfficientNetB7(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
efficient.trainable = False

# Your dataset: 1 channel only
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 1))

# Convert grayscale (1 channel) to RGB (3 channels)
x = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(x))(inputs)

# Application model
x = efficient(x, training=False)

# Top-net layers
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, x)

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics =['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_split=0.3, epochs=20, verbose=1, batch_size=16)
```

### **BUT**

Did you check the `trainY` labels? There is something wrong, you have only one class:

```
>>> np.unique(trainY, return_counts=True)
(array([0.]), array([16766]))
```

---

**Old answer**

You forgot to freeze the weights of `efficient` layer to use transfer learning and load weights from imagenet.

```
efficient = EfficientNetB7(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 1))
efficient.trainable = False  # <- HERE
```

If you don't want to use transfer learning, you need more epochs and a lot of patience :-)

**Update**

> My dataset consists of images and has 3 classes

So why your last layer contains only 1 output unit?

```
model = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="softmax")(model)
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252706/discussion-on-answer-by-corralien-why-is-accuracy-0-when-training-with-cnn-wher); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.